# Detecting similar elements in jagged arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is there a way to detect similar elements within multidimensional arrays? For example:

```
int[][] arrayA = {{1 , 2}, {4 , 6}, {3, 7}};
int[][] arrayB = {{3 , 2}, {1 , 2}, {8, 5}};
```

Both `arrayA` and `arrayB` have the element `{1 , 2}`. (Or simply, any element in common) Is there a way to detect that it's `true`?

Comment: these are **jagged** arrays, not **multidimensional**

Comment: Ahh I see. But is there still a way to find the elements regardless if it's jagged?

Comment: @RogueCSDev ANY element in common, yes.

Comment: for int i in array1, for int j in array2, blah-blah - you know, write a code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just need to code the logic and you can detect.

```
    bool result = false;
    foreach (var arrayAItem in arrayA)
    {
        foreach (var arrayBItem in arrayB)
        {
            if (arrayAItem.SequenceEqual(arrayBItem))
            {
                result = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (result == true)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```

and a one liner

```
bool result = arrayA.Any(arrayAItem => arrayB.Any(arrayBItem => arrayAItem.SequenceEqual(arrayBItem)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along this?

```
arrayA.Where(arr => arrayB.Any(arr2 => arr1.OrderBy(x => x)
                                           .SequenceEquals(arr.OrderBy(x => x)))).ToArray()
```

You can remove the two `OrderBy` calls if you want, depending on how you wish to consider two arrays "the same".

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give you the answer without just feeding you code, but:

For each element in Array A, check if it's equal to each element in Array B. So basically, you'd need a nested `foreach`. If you want to record which elements they have in common, add them to a `List<ElementType>` (not an array since you want to dynamically populate it).

It's not quite that simple since your arrays are nested. You can't just check `arrayA[x] == arrayB[x]` because you'd be comparing arrays, which are reference types (it would return false unless they both pointed to the same piece of memory). Instead, you'll have to add one more loop inside of the two `foreach`es you already have to check each `int` in `arrayA` against the correlating one in `arrayB`. `int` is a value type, so an `==` comparison would behave how you'd expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do this (and not only):

```
var commonItems = from innerA in arrayA
                  from innerB in arrayB
                  where innerA.SequenceEqual(innerB)
                  select innerA;
bool anyCommon = commonItems.Any();
var firstCommon = commonItems.FirstOrDefault();
var commonCount = commonItems.Count();
```

I guess the variable names are self explanatory :-)

Answer (score 0):

The following code becomes lengthened, but will give you the output you want:

```
    private void TestArrays()
    {
        int[,] arrayA = new[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 4, 6 }, { 3, 7 } };
        int[,] arrayB = new[,] { { 3, 2 }, { 1, 2 }, { 8, 5 } };

        int parentLengthA = arrayA.GetLength(0);
        int childLengthA = arrayA.GetLength(1);
        int parentLengthB = arrayB.GetLength(0);
        int childLengthB = arrayB.GetLength(1);

        int[] itemsOfA;
        int[] itemsOfB;

        List<int[]> matchedArrays = new List<int[]>();

        for (int i = 0; i < parentLengthA; i++)
        {
            itemsOfA = new int[childLengthA];

            for (int j = 0; j < parentLengthB; j++)
            {
                itemsOfB = new int[childLengthB];

                bool isMatched = true;

                if (itemsOfA.Length != itemsOfB.Length)
                {
                    isMatched = false;
                    break;
                }

                for (int k = 0; k < itemsOfA.Length; k++)
                {
                    if (arrayA[i, k] != arrayB[j, k])
                    {
                        isMatched = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        itemsOfA[k] = arrayA[i, k];
                    }
                }

                if (isMatched)
                {
                    matchedArrays.Add(itemsOfA);
                }
            }
        }

        //Just to output the matched array(s)
        if (matchedArrays.Count > 0)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (int[] matchedArray in matchedArrays)
            {
                foreach (int i in matchedArray)
                {
                    sb.Append(i + ",");
                }

                sb.AppendLine();
            }

            MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
```